# Google Authentication using Cognito and Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, amazon-cognito

I've searched far and wide after a solution to my problems but can't seem to find any. My problem is that I need to create a google-authenticator with the help of AWS Cognito. For any other programming language, there seems to be an easy solution but for Xamarin forms that I write it in, there seems to be no documentation at all. So I'm now reaching out to you here to see if there is someone that can help me with my problem. 
I'm supposed to press a button and get redirected to the google login page and then get back the data from google. This is what I've got so far.

```
void OnGoogleLoginClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials credentials = new Amazon.CognitoIdentity.CognitoAWSCredentials(
        "eu-west-2:580dbdc0-4979-4a25-a4ab-7dc90d7f2a2d", // Identity pool ID
        Amazon.RegionEndpoint.EUWest2 // Region
        );

    string googleClientId = null;
    string googleRedirect = null;

    switch (Device.RuntimePlatform)
    {
        case Device.iOS:
            googleClientId = Constants.GoogleClientId;
            googleRedirect = Constants.GoogleRedirectUrl;
            break;
        case Device.Android:
            googleClientId = Constants.GoogleClientId;
            googleRedirect = Constants.GoogleRedirectUrl;
            break;
    } 
}
```

This is What i've come up with so far but i can't seem to figure the rest out. Answers are apprechiated greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Have you tried to use Xamarin Essentials Web Authenticator?

You can use `webauthenticator` with `AWS` Hosted Web UI.

`AWS` Provides a Hosted Web UI witch handles with a pretty cool solution the authentication throught socials.